# Correct placement of strtolower() in this code

Tags: php

I want to add strtolower() to the below code

```
$skin = new skin('movie/similar_rows'); $similar_rows = '';
while ($TMPL = mysql_fetch_assoc($similar_result)) {
$TMPL['title_encoded'] = str_replace("+", "-", urlencode($TMPL['title']));
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$skin = new skin('movie/similar_rows'); $similar_rows = '';
while ($TMPL = mysql_fetch_assoc($similar_result)) {
$TMPL['title_encoded'] = strtolower(str_replace("+", "-", urlencode($TMPL['title'])))
```

Any suggestions?

I'm pretty new to coding so don't jump on me!

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? Haven't you lost semicolon in the end?

Comment: The page will show as a white page if I use the code i tried.

Comment: make some research about php error logs

Comment: If you create an Answer Zerkms, I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the semicolon in the end of the line you've modified.

To debug such cases (assuming you develop on local machine, not in production) it's a good idea to:

1. set up `error_reporting` level to `E_ALL`
2. output errors to the screen: `display_errors = on`

You can read about these directives in details in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting